# Loop through each child in a div with data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, custom-data-attribute

I have multiple `<div>`s, based on a `<select>`, where each one contains multiple `<input>`s and sometimes a disabled `<select>` with a fixed value. Now I'm trying to loop through each of the divs and put all inputs and select values into an **array** and push that array into the "master" array.

However this seems not to work to well.
I feel like I'm already close but yet so far. :(

```
var dummy = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= toSend.count; i++){
        var temp = [];
        $("div[data-row="+i+"]").children('input, select').each(function(){
            temp.push( $(this).val() );
        });

        dummy.push(temp);
    };

    console.log(dummy);
```

toSend.count is the counting of how many div's with `data-row` exist.
The HTML looks like this :

```
<div id="container">
   <div data-row="1">
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="text"/>
   </div>
   <div data-row="2">
     <input type="text"/>
     <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Aaah, nevermind this was my own stupidity! I'm generating the div's via AJAX
and I copy pasted myself an error.
All div's had `data-row=1`, no wonder it packed all in one array **>.<**

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? The order of logging? That's because of how `console.log` works

Comment: The jQuery "each" method isn't guaranteed to loop through the items in any particular order.

Comment: I've added the HTML.

@blgt No the problem is that it puts all this in one array in the whole for loop and not in an array per loop. eg. I expect to get 2 arrays when I've got 2 divs with `data-row` but I always get a single one back.

Comment: Array or Console? If you want help, you need to post the code you're actually troubleshooting.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann edited it for clarity, I've just left console.log from the debugging

Comment: What is "toSend.anz"??

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code posted in the update: http://jsfiddle.net/3fp9f3dz/ Result is one array containing two arrays containing two strings each

Comment: I'm getting Array( `["Foo", "Bar", "John", "Doe"]` ) where as I'm expecting I should get something back like Array(  Array(`["Foo", "Bar"]`) , Array( `["John", "Doe"]` ) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief code for what you want to achieve.

```
$("div[data-row="+i+"]")each(function(){ 
    $(this).children('input, select').each(function(){
        console.log(  $(this).val());
        console.log("Child Change");
    });
      console.log("Div Change");
});
```

Comment: OP's problem was (apparently) caused by a typo, this answer doesn't (and indeed can't) address that at all. Also, there's a typo here as well which would result in a syntax error

Answer (score 3):

(Edit: pays to read the code more completely)

Since the `toSend` variable is just the DIVs with a `data-row` attribute, no need to loop over `toSend` to find the DIVs:

```
var dummy = [];

$("#container div[data-row]").each(function() {
    var temp = [];

    $(this).children("input, select").each(function() {
        temp.push(this.value);
    });

    dummy.push(temp);
});
```

After this, you might not even need the `toSend` variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

.each function from jquery is not syncrounious, use for instead.

```
var $tmp;

for(var i = 1; i <= toSend.count; i++)
{
     $tmp = $("div[data-row="+i+"]").children('input, select');

     for(var ii = 1,len = $tmp.length; ii <= len; ii++){
        console.log(  $tmp.eq(ii).val());
     };

     console.log("New line #" + i);
};
```

Comment: Having three `;` in a `for` will cause a syntax error

Comment: sorry that should be  for(var ii = 1,len = $tmp.length; ii <= len; ii++){